# Types of consistency: practical difference

Tags: convergence, estimators, consistency

Consistency is usually a desired property for an estimator. We have the definition of **consistency** for an estimator $T_n$ for $\theta$, stating that it converges in probability to $\theta$, and the definition **strong consistency**, which asserts that it converges $\mathbb{P}_{\theta}$-almost surely to $\theta$. The latter implies the first.

I have no problem with the mathematical definitions or how to work with them. My question is distinguishing practically these two types of consistency.

For instance, suppose I have $T_n$, which is strongly consistent to $\theta$, and $R_n$, which is consistent, but not strongly consistent. What do I gain, in practice, from the fact that $T_n$ is strongly consistent?

If I made a simulation study to observe the convergence of both estimators, would there be a noticeable difference? Can $R_n$ have a better convergence rate than $T_n$?

Comment: A question that is similar in spirit though on another topic: [pointwise convergence vs. uniform convergence of estimators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271843).

Comment: Another related Q:  [Is there a statistical application that requires strong consistency?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72859/is-there-a-statistical-application-that-requires-strong-consistency/74338#74338)